# Is a full or partial sitemap better on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, google, sitemap

I heard on an older podcast that

- Google spider traffic is significant on Stack Overflow, and
- the sitemap only contains entries for the newest 50,000 pages.

Would it be more efficient, in terms of cutting the Google spider traffic, to add every page to the sitemap?

- It would allow Google to recognize the pages that have not been changed since they were indexed, without accessing those files individually.
- It would take 40+ sitemap files, but the files with older pages could be updated only once a month or so (for new comments, etc.)